# Resized GIF images change to black

Tags: php, gd, gif

I have a script that resizes uploaded images. I added in some instructions to transform any transparency in GIFs to white. It usually works fine, but in some cases the resized GIF is completely black. (Note that I'm using these images for PDFs, so I can't use CSS to deal with this...). Anyway, I'm a newbie when it comes to PHP image manipulation, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here are two sample GIFs. The first one works fine while the second one is changed to black.

[image]

[image]

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
elseif ($fileType == 'gif') {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecolortransparent($dst, imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($dst, false);
    imagesavealpha($dst, true);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height); 
    imagegif($dst, $file);
}
```

Comment: Neither of those gifs have transparency.

Comment: The second image is not a gif.

Answer (score 0):

First transform your second image into gif format. For this, either use any image manipulation tool(gimp/photoshop) or prefix below code snippet:

```
// Load the JPEG
$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
// Save the image as a GIF
imagegif($jpeg, $file);
```

In given code snippet, you are using imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127) function which will adding full transparency in your image. Instead of this, try to use imagecolorallocate($dst, 0, 0, 0) function or don't use color parameter in imagecolortransparent() function.